# Unable to start Chrome in Selenium Web-driver (Java)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver , via Java & TestNG.

I've just tried the following code: (for starting chrome browser),

```
package testng1package;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.AssertJUnit;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;


public class TestNGFile {

    //using firefox
    //public WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver() ;

    //using Chrome
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://Users//Roey//Desktop//chromedriver.exe");
    public WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();   
    String baseurl = "http://newtours.demoaut.com/" ;

    @BeforeTest
    public void StartBrowser() {

    }

    @Test
    public void Test1() {

        driver.get(baseurl);
        String expectedTitle = "Welcome: Mercury Tours" ; 
        String actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
        AssertJUnit.assertEquals(actualTitle , expectedTitle) ;
        driver.quit();        
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void terminateBrowser() {
        driver.quit();              
    }

}
```

the test contain error on the system.setproperty, and says:

> Multiple markers at this line 
>       - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced 
>        construct(s) 
>       - Syntax error on tokens, delete these 
>        tokens

If I am cutting and pasting this code line into the @test - it's ok, but I want to use it from the `@BeforeTest` or the beginning ( as it is it now).

Comment: You need to show us more code. Also post the entirety of the error stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Ok so first setup your driver in a method.
Secondly the path to your chromedriver on windows will need backslashes, not forward slashed.

This works.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.AssertJUnit;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;   

public class TestNGFile {
    @Test
    public void Test1() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Roey\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();
        String baseurl = "http://newtours.demoaut.com/" ;
        chromeDriver.get(baseurl);
        String expectedTitle = "Welcome: Mercury Tours" ;
        String actualTitle = chromeDriver.getTitle();
        AssertJUnit.assertEquals(actualTitle , expectedTitle) ;
        chromeDriver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: tnx , its working that way , 
but is there way to put the chrome driver under
'BeforeTest' - and use it during the @Test ?

Comment: Do you really need to do anything in a @BeforeTest? Just declare WebDriver chromeDriver at a class level.

Answer (score 0):

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/dell/Downloads/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver d = new ChromeDriver();
    d.get("Any URL");
```

Note-In the location of chromedriver.exe single forward slash would do.Hope this works fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Eclipse. I place the chromedriver.exe in the project workspace, you don't need the full path in `System.setProperty` then as Selenium knows where to look. I then set it in the `@Before`.

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Maven add these 2 dependencies in your pom.xml and you will be fine and now you can remove the System.setProperty line. With this technique the project has less hardcode method.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Also you need to add this line to you preject.

```
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
```